# Creating a contingency table from grouped values

Tags: r, contingency

I have a data frame, "dat", with a factor, "letters" (which has three levels, "A", "B", and "C"), and a numeric vector, "numbers" (with values from 1 to 80):

```
dat <- data.frame(letters = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),
                  numbers = sample(80, 15, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to create a contingency table, in which the levels "B" and "C" are grouped, and values are grouped into those above and those below 40.5.

That is, the resulting contingency table should look like this (with different frequencies, of course):

```
> table(...)
       numbers
letters 1:40 41:80
      A    2     3
  B + C    4     6
```

I have created that table by first introducing two new columns in my data frame and then creating the table from those:

```
dat$two.letters <- "A"
dat[dat$letters != "A", ]$two.letters <- "B + C"
dat$two.letters <- as.factor(dat$two.letters)
dat$two.numbers <- "1:40"
dat[dat$numbers > 40, ]$two.numbers <- "41:80"
dat$two.numbers <- as.factor(dat$two.numbers)
table(dat$two.letters, dat$two.numbers)

        1:40 41:80
  A        3     1
  B + C    6     5
```

But I want to create that table **without introducing new columns** or building a separate data frame. Rather I would like to group the values in the `table()` command.

Is that possible?

Comment: @bouncyball Brilliant! Why not make that an answer so I can accept?

Comment: why not just `with(dat, table(letters == 'A', numbers <= 40))`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Ever more brilliant! Although I must say that I like the ability to label my output using bouncyball's method. Having two dimensions that are both labelled "TRUE" and "FALSE" confuses me a bit.

Comment: you can always add the labels afterwards ;-)

Comment: @user8183921 posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the ever helpful [`ifelse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) function to relabel your data points. We also use the [`with`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/with.html) function to avoid extra typing:

```
with(dat, 
    table(ifelse(letters == 'A', 'A', 'B+C'), ifelse(numbers <= 40, '1:40','41:80')))

      1:40 41:80
  A      1     2
  B+C    4     8
```

#### data (note the usage of `set.seed`)

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(letters = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE),
                  numbers = sample(80, 15, replace = TRUE))
```